# Flutter - Future Builder with service and model

Tags: listview, flutter

I´m trying to use FutureBuilder to show infinite list. I want to use model and service in different .dart files so i need inject the service in the FutureBuilder. I think the problem that the service doesn´t return a list, but i don´t know why. The code is

Model

```
class Datameter {
  int idAgrupacion;
  int nroSerie;
  String fecha;

  ///
  double latitud;
  double longitud;
  String contador;
  String sensor;

  Datameter(
      {this.idAgrupacion,
      this.nroSerie,
      this.fecha,

      ///
      this.latitud,
      this.longitud,
      this.contador,
      this.sensor});

  factory Datameter.fromJson(json) => new Datameter(
        nroSerie: json["nro_serie"],
        idAgrupacion: json["id_agrupacion"],
        fecha: json["fecha"],
        //
        latitud: json["latitud"],
        longitud: json["longitud"],
        contador: json["contador"],
        sensor: json["sensor"],
      );
}
```

Service

```
  static Future<Datameter> getDatameters(dropdown) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('token');
    final response = await http.get(
        'http://192.168.3.64:8080/datameter/agrupacion/info?agrupacion=' +
            dropdown +
            '&limite=0',
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Token " + token
        }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      return responseJson["body"].map((item) => Datameter.fromJson(item)).toList();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

View

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: DatameterService.getInstalations("2"),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return snapshot.data;  ListView.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tint,
                            size: 24, color: Colors.black),
                        trailing: Text(DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')
                            .format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                snapshot.data[i]['fecha']))
                            .toString()),
                        onTap: null,
                        title: Text(
                          snapshot.data[i]['nro_serie'],
                        ));
                  });
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }),
```

The problem: Return 'type *DatameterList* is not a subtype of type 'Widget''

So: What is the rigth way to show list using FutureBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

The builder function should return a Widget, something like you have commented out:

```
 FutureBuilder(
      future: DatameterService.getInstalations("2"),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tint, size: 24, color: Colors.black),
                    trailing: Text(DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')
                        .format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                            snapshot.data[i]['fecha'])
                        ).toString()
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                    title: Text(
                      snapshot.data[i]['nro_serie'],
                    ),
                  );
              });
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }),
```

Comment: I comment because return; 'Class DatameterList' has no instance getter 'lenght'. Receiver: Instance of 'DatameterList'. Tried calling: length. Aparently can´t take length of elements.

Comment: Well, that is because your future does not return a list: 'return DatameterList.fromJson(responseJson);'

Comment: And how can i convert the element into into a list? I´m new in flutter...

Comment: That will depend on how responseJson is received, could you provide an example of the payload?. But basically, if responseJson is something like "[{}, {}...]" yo can  just  map the values to a list: responseJson.map((item) => DatameterList.fromJson(item)).toList()

Comment: Return _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Datameter' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Comment: Just change the return on getInstalations to return a list of Datameter, you can use map as I show above to convert from JSON array to List<Datameter>.  Also, set the return type to Future<List<Datameter>> will help the IDE to validate that you are returning  the right type.

Comment: I update the code of the question. Now return _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Datameter>')

Comment: That may be because the return null, try returning an empty list instead of null on error.